# Couldn't get text from the textfield Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have encounter a problem with my if else statement. I can't execute my if else statement. Actually the program should get the text from the text field and then convert to integer and validate whether the item id is found or not.

below is my partial coding:

```
Integer itmID = new Integer(inputItemID.getText());
  Integer brwID = new Integer(inputBorrowerID.getText());
  Item itm = parent.getItems().get(itmID);
  Borrower brw = parent.getBorrowers().get(brwID);
  if (itm == null) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Item ID not found","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
  }
```

Comment: What error/exception you are getting? Did you debug the code?

Comment: @almasshaikh once i enter the itemID its showing Item ID not found. So i guess my code got some error on the top of the if-else statement.

Comment: And how is your parent's items populated. Can you paste that code?

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving item like `Item itm = parent.getItems().get(itmID);` , i assume that getItems() is some kind of collection . You are getting `itm = null` because your `getItems()` doesn't contain any item with given itemId.